# Unusual Hadoop error - tasks get killed on their own

Tags: hadoop

When I run my hadoop job I get the following error:

**Request received to kill task 'attempt_201202230353_23186_r_000004_0' by user
Task has been KILLED_UNCLEAN by the user**

The logs appear to be clean. I run 28 reducers, and this doesnt happen for all the reducers. It happens for a selected few and the reducer starts again. I fail to understand this. Also other thing I have noticed is that for a small dataset, I rarely see this error!

Comment: Is the job failing due to this issue? Are you running with speculative execution enabled?

Comment: Yes, speculative execution is set to true. The job doesnt fail, it eventually finishes with lots of kiiled/failed reducers which overall increases the job completion time!

Comment: @Pradeep Gollakota Also, I have observed that, the reducers that get killed or failed once keep on getting killed like 8-9 times until they succeed and the reducers that are not killed even once are clean throughout the job!

Comment: Did you increase the max number of task attempts? The default setting allows for 4 attempt per task. If a task fails 4 times the job is killed. I will need additional information in order to help you debug this problem. There are any number of causes for this, ranging from data distribution to performance issue's stemming from high memory usage to bad node's in your cluster. Do you have any logs that you can post? Are the reduce tasks that are failing always failing on the same nodes? What profiling have you done to resolve this issue? Any additional information would be helpful.

Comment: with speculative execution, one taks may be assigned to several reducers. Now if any one of them completes fast enough, others would be killed. check your output data on small data set, if its correct, everything is still fine.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the reducers that are getting killed, have clean logs. I have not changed the default settings for the attempts before a task gets killed. They all fail on the same node, or the nodes of the same rack and once they fail they keep on failing!! My files contain 4M records and on a good day when no reducers fail, my job time is 4 hours abd with the failing reducers around 8 hours! Is there a way I can force all the data to be map-reduced on the machines of the same rack(I am not sure if that is the problem)!

Comment: RFT, I am running into the same problem. I tried turning speculative execution off but the KILLED_UNCLEAN error still comes up, and the reducer starts again. Just curious if you found a fix to the problem.

Comment: This could also be due to the task manager freeing up resources for a higher-priority user. Are there other large jobs running at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

There are three things to try:

**Setting a Counter**
If Hadoop sees a counter for the job progressing then it won't kill it (see Arockiaraj Durairaj's answer.) This seems to be the most elegant as it could allow you more insight into long running jobs and were the hangups may be.

**Longer Task Timeouts**
Hadoop jobs timeout after 10 minutes by default. Changing the timeout is somewhat brute force, but could work. Imagine analyzing audio files that are generally 5MB files (songs), but you have a few 50MB files (entire album). Hadoop stores an individual file per block. So if your HDFS block size is 64MB then a 5MB file and a 50 MB file would both require 1 block (64MB) (see here http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/, and here [Small files and HDFS blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562934/small-files-and-hdfs-blocks).) However, the 5MB job would run faster than the 50MB job. Task timeout can be increased in the code (mapred.task.timeout) for the job per the answers to this similar question: [How to fix "Task attempt_201104251139_0295_r_000006_0 failed to report status for 600 seconds."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864589/how-to-fix-task-attempt-201104251139-0295-r-000006-0-failed-to-report-status-fo?rq=1)

**Increase Task Attempts**
Configure Hadoop to make more than the 4 default attempts (see Pradeep Gollakota's answer). This is the most brute force method of the three. Hadoop will attempt the job more times, but you could be masking an underlying issue (small servers, large data blocks, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using counter(hadoop counter) in your reduce logic? It looks like hadoop is not able to determine whether your reduce program is running or hanging. It waits for a few minutes and kills it, even though your logic may be still executing.