# What can cause hadoop kill reducer task an retry

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

my hadoop job has a very high ‘Killed Task Attempts’ number on its reducer tasks, I check the status of killed task:

```
Request received to kill task 'attempt_201308122006_41526_r_000030_1' by user
-------
Task has been KILLED_UNCLEAN by the user
```

and no stdout and stderr logs

what could cause this ? and how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506176/unusual-hadoop-error-tasks-get-killed-on-their-own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not the speculative execution, it could be the Fair Scheduler kicked in claiming task trackers for pool with minMaps and minReduces.

Answer (score 3):

If you have speculative execution turned on, then you will potentially see a number of map / reduce tasks that will be 'killed'. This is due to hadoop running long running tasks on more than a single task tracker, and the first one to complete 'wins' while the others are killed off.

In general i would only worry about the task attempts that 'failed' in the job tracker

Try turning speculative execution off:

`mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution = false`
`mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution = false`

Comment: thanks Chris, I had turned speculative execution off in before job starts but still have a big ‘Killed Task Attempts’ number

Comment: Well in that case, is someone else killing your jobs (via the command line or in the job tracker web UI?).

Comment: It will not I think... if someone kill it, the job will fail eventually, while my job get successfully run in the end after a very long time

Comment: You can kill an individual task (usually up to 4 times before the entire job will fail)